# How to change format of override method in Omnisharp

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, omnisharp

I am looking for a way to replace the default format of override in Omnisharp on Sublime Text from

```
public override void FUNCTIONNAME(){
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

to

```
public override void FUNCTIONNAME(){
    base.FUNCTIONNAME();
}
```

for Unity3D. Is this possible inside of the config file for Omnisharp? Also, I am having issues where creating a new override function puts that function at the bottom of my class.